# Will GNOME and GTK libs bloat up my KDE?

Tags: gnome, kde, libraries, gtk, application

I want to use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/). I installed it previously under Kubuntu and it needed a lot of libs.

What bothered me most was that Kubuntu wanted me to restart, that is rare for OS's nowadays and in general means that something was added to startup procedures.

So will these libs bloat my KDE up and get loaded even if I don't start Shutter? To be clear, as long as it's only disk space that not what I mean by bloat.

Please take this more as a general question about installing GNOME apps on KDE and not so much about Shutter and the libs it needs. Maybe you can help me understand the technical background a bit better.

Comment: Not sure 100% but I think the restart notice was maybe caused by other things that updated during the process of apt-getting stuff for this.

Comment: That could be right. I've installed shutter a few times and I don't recall being asked to restart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you are on very old/low spec hardware, running `gnome/gtk` apps in `KDE` (or `kde/qt` apps in `GNOME`) should not have any noticeable impact on performance.
When you're on `KDE`, `qt/kde` libs are already loaded in memory, `gtk/gnome` libs are not. It's only when you fire-up a `gtk/gnome` app that `gtk/gnome` libs are loaded, the side effect being a higher memory usage (additional libs are loaded into memory) and possibly (on a slow hdd) a longer initial start-up time of the `gtk` app.